# Simple Product Can Configure Once but Not Twice

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, simple-product

I have a simple product with custom options and when I go to the actual frontend product page, I can customize the product and the price adjusts correctly depending on the selections.  After adding the product to the cart, I go back to the same product page and customize the product a second time, the price does not update on the product page, only when it is added to the cart.

The Console does not show any errors or warnings.  I am using an extension (Custom Math Pricing) which manipulates the pricing slightly.  Their head of support said it sounds like a template issue or a jQuery issue.  If I clean out the browser cache and cookies, I can customize the product again but that removes the 1st item from the cart.  Does anyone know how I can debug this or solve it with minimal Magento experience?

Magento 1.9.1

Extension: Custom Math Pricing - Mico Solutions

Theme: Argento Theme - Mall

If you would like code provided, please let me know what you'd like to see and I can paste it, I don't know where to begin with this one.  Just put your request in the comments.

Comment: The extension has Ajax requests? If so, check the network tab for the response that is returned when you go back to the product a second time to customize it.

Comment: Okay, I checked the network tab and I am not certain what I am looking for here, it shows all the js, css and image files loaded to the page, I do not see any errors or warnings.

Comment: On Firefox, https://www.evernote.com/l/Ak-BKy87RkBBRYqbaIhEbkPVx_-GFJGJ_F8, there's a Network > Response tab.

Comment: Okay, I am reviewing the Network Response tab.  The html returned 200 (ok) but nearly everything else appears to be 304 (not modified).  What should I be looking for specifically?

Comment: *IF* you have an Ajax request going out when you click (customize) on the product page, you'll see a new request entry appear, and it will return a response. This response will contain some kind of error message if the request failed.

Comment: If I refresh the page, I get a large list of files, however, if I click from the cart back to the product page, only the html code shows on the network tab.  Is this normal behavior?

Comment: Nothing on the network list is ajax, it's all js, html, images and css.

Comment: When I add the product to the cart, a json entry appears and doesn't appear to have any errors.

Comment: You should just place a link to the product page so other people can take a look at it, instead of reading description of a vague problem.

Comment: It's not on a public host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in the extension.  Download the new version and you should be up and running! You should always try to keep up to date with your extensions and themes.  I know that Argento has a lot of built in extensions so you're going to want to keep that up to date as much as possible.